# How to get a separate XML for each ASIN ? Amazon-MWS

Tags: php, xml, amazon-mws

I have 1 request with 20 ASINs. I get the response in the form of XML with 20 ASINs. I want to get one XML - Respons for one ASIN and Save in txt-File (20 XML).
But I can do this only if in request 1 ASIN and not 20. But then the process is very slow. What should I do? 
Question number 2.
How can I create 1 XML with all ASIN (eg 1000) ?

```
    $arr = file('asin.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$arr_chunks = array_chunk($arr, 20);

$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();

//$request->setASINList($asin_list);
$request->setItemCondition('used');

foreach ($arr_chunks as $value){
    $value = $value;
    $asin_list->setASIN($value);
$request->setASINList($asin_list);
 sleep(1);
 invokeGetLowestOfferListingsForASIN($service, $request);
}

  function invokeGetLowestOfferListingsForASIN(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
      try {
        $response = $service->GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN();


 file_put_contents('asin2.xml', $response->toXML());
        echo ("Service Response\n");
        echo ("=============================================================================\n");

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        echo $dom->saveXML();
       // echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
```

Here is an example of XML (asin2.xml)

```
<GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse
    xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
    <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult
        ASIN='3944660110' status='Success'>
        <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
        <Product>
            <Identifiers>
                <MarketplaceASIN>
                    <MarketplaceId>A1PA6795UKMFR9</MarketplaceId>
                    <ASIN>3944660110</ASIN>
                </MarketplaceASIN>
            </Identifiers>
            <LowestOfferListings></LowestOfferListings>
        </Product>
    </GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
    <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult
        ASIN='3000383964' status='Success'>
        <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
        <Product>
            <Identifiers>
                <MarketplaceASIN>
                    <MarketplaceId>A1PA6795UKMFR9</MarketplaceId>
                    <ASIN>3000383964</ASIN>
                </MarketplaceASIN>
            </Identifiers>
            <LowestOfferListings>
                <LowestOfferListing>
                    <Qualifiers>
                        <ItemCondition>Used</ItemCondition>
                        <ItemSubcondition>Good</ItemSubcondition>
                        <FulfillmentChannel>Merchant</FulfillmentChannel>
                        <ShipsDomestically>True</ShipsDomestically>
                        <ShippingTime>
                            <Max>0-2 days</Max>
                        </ShippingTime>
                        <SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>98-100%
                        </SellerPositiveFeedbackRating>
                    </Qualifiers>
                    <NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>1
                    </NumberOfOfferListingsConsidered>
                    <SellerFeedbackCount>1388</SellerFeedbackCount>
                    <Price>
                        <LandedPrice>
                            <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>31.80</Amount>
                        </LandedPrice>
                        <ListingPrice>
                            <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>28.80</Amount>
                        </ListingPrice>
                        <Shipping>
                            <CurrencyCode>EUR</CurrencyCode>
                            <Amount>3.00</Amount>
                        </Shipping>
                    </Price>
                    <MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>False</MultipleOffersAtLowestPrice>
                </LowestOfferListing>
            </LowestOfferListings>
        </Product>
    </GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
    <GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult
        ASIN='3000556575' status='Success'>
        <AllOfferListingsConsidered>true</AllOfferListingsConsidered>
        <Product>
            <Identifiers>
                <MarketplaceASIN>
                    <MarketplaceId>A1PA6795UKMFR9</MarketplaceId>
                    <ASIN>3000556575</ASIN>
                </MarketplaceASIN>
            </Identifiers>
            <LowestOfferListings></LowestOfferListings>
        </Product>
    </GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>3caac4dc-ca52-446f-9f4b-a8da2d685ce7</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResponse>
```

Comment: If you add a sample XML file, it may help.

Comment: I've added it. But it is always only in a line. Sorry. I do not know how to do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your XML document, you can use XPath to list each ASIN, this can then be output as XML and you can save each segment to an appropriate file...

```
   $dom = new DOMDocument ();
   $dom->load ( 't1.xml' );
   $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
   $xp->registerNamespace("default", 
                "http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01");
    foreach ( $xp->query("//default:GetLowestOfferListingsForASINResult") as $asin ) {
        echo "For ASIN:".$asin->getAttribute('ASIN').PHP_EOL;
        echo "ASIN=".$xp->evaluate ("string(descendant::default:MarketplaceASIN/default:ASIN/text())", $asin) .PHP_EOL;

        echo $dom->saveXML($asin).PHP_EOL;
        $prices = $xp->query("descendant::default:Price", $asin );
        foreach ( $prices as $price )   {
            echo "LandedPrice=".$xp->evaluate("string(descendant::default:LandedPrice/default:Amount/text())",$price).PHP_EOL;
            echo "ListingPrice=".$xp->evaluate("string(descendant::default:ListingPrice/default:Amount/text())",$price).PHP_EOL;
            echo "Shipping=".$xp->evaluate("string(descendant::default:Shipping/default:Amount/text())",$price).PHP_EOL;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Many Thanks! It is working.
I try to click on "Votes", but get "
Tank for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. "

Soryy. But you helped me. THANK YOU.

Comment: Sorry that I ask again. I have an additional question. How from this line - from $asin to receive all prices (the final price together with delivery)?

Comment: I've updated the code, it will extract the various prices from each node.

Comment: The result shows only one price many times. If only one ASIN and 4 sellers, 4 times shows the lowest price, but not all prices of sellers.

Comment: Sorry - as I only had 1 set of prices it seemed to be OK.  I've changed it to use `descendant` in the XPath to make it only use the current node.

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question. I'm trying to get the asin. According to your example. But it does not. Why? Echo "ASIN =". $ Xp-> evaluate ("string(descendant::default:MarketplaceASIN / default: ASIN / text ())", $ price) .PHP_EOL

Comment: I've added this to the code, the problem is that your trying to find the ASIN in the `<price>` element of the XML, moving this to find it within the outer loop should work.